# Interferences between anaconda and ubuntu 14.04 base python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda

I am very new with python, so please bear with me and be gentle

I recently installed anaconda and spyder in my ubuntu 14.04. When I call python in my console and I am having some different results when running python from the console and python from spyder

### Results running from the console

if I call python

```
python
```

I get the following message:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
```

and I can import pandas with no problem:

```
import pandas
```

with spyder however

### Spyder

this is the opening message I get

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Imported NumPy 1.8.2, SciPy 0.13.3, Matplotlib 1.3.1
```

And if I try to import pandas

```
Import pandas
```

I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Clearly I have two different versions of python in my computer, I would like to have only one (Hopefully the one with anaconda since it comes with more dependencies I understand).

Comment: So... just use Anaconda and uninstall Spyder?

Answer (score 1):

"Clearly I have two different versions of python in my computer, I would like to have only one (Hopefully the one with anaconda since it comes with more dependencies I understand)."
As a wise man once said, "It would be bad.". The link leads to a better answer but the short answer is that in 14.04, system level dependencies require its Python install. Removing it would likely break your operation system install.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/315015/how-can-i-remove-python-2-7-after-installing-python-3-3

As for pandas
Anaconda hopes to simplify the process especially for scientist so it installs pandas for you.  You can see this by typing 
help("modules")
You should see it in the Anaconda install but not in the Spyder install.
How does this work?  If you
import sys; sys.path
a series of directories will be returned.  pandas had been installed in one of the directories related to the Anaconda install.  That directory will not be visible in the Spyder version.